# Upgrading pip/installing django - [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am having issues with installing django and upgrading pip. I don't know how I began running into these issues, but when I go to type `django-admin startproject mysite` it gives me an error:

> -bash: django-admin: command not found

I go ahead and type `pip install Django` and I then receive this error:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

When upgrading pip...

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

I believe the issue lies within `[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]`. I don't know how to go about fixing it so that I can use django and upgrade my pip version.

If I type `python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"`, I get `OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`. Do note that I was running django with no issues before these issues came to fruition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade pip, I typed into command prompt `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3`.

To be able to run the django website on my machine, I had to use `python3 manage.py runserver`. The trick here was to use `python3` instead of `python`.