# Python3 Virtual Environment not using the globally installed pip version

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have globally installed pip 21.2.4, but each time that I create a Virtual Environment an install a module I get the following warning:

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.

Then I update the pip version in the Virtual Environment as follow:

$ pip3 install --upgrade pip==21.2.4

But this change is only for this Virtual Environment and I have to repeat the same process each time I create a new Virtual Environment.

How could I do for all new Virtual Environments created used the latest pip version as I have globally?

Comment: What command do you use to create the virtual environment? What Python version do you use to create the virtual environment?

Comment: I use the following command: 

python3 -m venv postgres-workspace

But when I activate the  virtual environment the following command:

$ which python

Returns:

postgres-workspace/bin/python

Comment: What is your version of Python (`python3 -V`)? Assuming it is a recent enough version of Python (3.9+), you should be able to use the following command `python3 -m venv --upgrade-deps postgres-workspace`, this will create a virtual environment as usual then update both pip and setuptools in that environment. But you need to use the flag for each creation.

Comment: @sinoroc I have Python 3.9.6. Your solution is right, in this way there is no warning. Thank you very much for your help. It's not possible for me to mark your answer as the right one because it is in a comment, if you write it in an answer I could mark it as correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56229305/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *Python 3.9* the `venv` command line utility has a `--upgrade-deps` option, which will force the udpdate of *pip* and *setuptools* within the newly created virtual environment. For example:

```
path/to/python3.9 -m venv --upgrade-deps something
```

***Related***:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360279

Answer (score 0):

changing your python version would certainly do it.

Comment: Hi @Iska, Could you please explain it with more details? I really don't know what you mean.